# XMLHttpRequest form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a form using XMLHttpRequest. This is my problem:

when the form is submitted and response is 0 (string), the message showed in the #output div is "Something went wrong..." (as it has to be);

instead, when the form is submitted and response is 1 (string), the message showed in the #output div is "1" - and not "SENT!" (as it should be).

**HTML**

```
<form id="contactform">
<input name="name" type="text">
<input name="surname" type="text">
<input name="email" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**JS**

```
const form = document.getElementById("contactform");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

form.onsubmit = () => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.open('POST', 'https:...');
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            showResponse(this.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => {
        showResponse("0");
    };
    return false;
};

showResponse = data => {
    var text;
    switch (data) {
        case "0":
            text = "Something went wrong...";
            break;
        case "1":
            text = "SENT!";
            break;
        default:
            text = data;
    }
    output.innerHTML = text;
};
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Check what the `response` actually is, ie check for hidden white spaces, see if `response.length` is 1 if it is more your server script is more than likely printing extra white space characters. For example in php scripts if you have extra spaces/lines after a closing php tag you will encounter this problem. If that is what is happening use trim()

Comment: Check `typeOf(data)` in the first line of your `showResponse` method.

Comment: @PatrickEvans:  actually, response.length is 3 and I don't know why. Response comes from a php file this way: 

echo "1";

Comment: Yea you probably have extra spaces after a closing `?>` tag. use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) on the response to get rid of them, `showResponse(this.response.trim())`

Comment: @PatrickEvans: thank you very much! This change solved the issue: switch (data.trim()) ...

Answer (score 0):

`this` reference problem, change as follow:

```
form.onsubmit = () => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.open('POST', 'https:...');
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            showResponse(this.response);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => {
        showResponse("0");
    };
    return false;
};
```